# Connect database .mdf dynamically and get all tables in this db

Tags: c#

My program should be able to choose any db(.mdf) and show all tables in this db. For examle, table "students"have a fields: "firstName", "SecondName", "dateOfBirth". But I recive an error that Access Denied. Operating system error 5 or 32.

```
// Open db
        private void btnOpenDatavase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Stream myStream = null;
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Data|*.mdf";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = false;

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                    {
                        using (myStream)
                        {

                            string fullPath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                            showTables(fullPath);

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        void showTables(string path)
        {

            String strConnection = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                          AttachDbFilename=" + path + ";" +
                          "Integrated Security=True;" +
                          "Connect Timeout=30;" +
                          "User Instance=False";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
            try
            {

                con.Open();

                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

                sqlCmd.Connection = con;
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES";

                SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

                DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
                sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
                comboBox1.DataSource = dtRecord;
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "TABLES";
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }


}
```

Comment: where is ur .mdf located? also make sure the window user has full rights on the database

Comment: @Sachu, mdf located on disc E. Its not a system disc. I enter as administator and i have a full rights.

Comment: @user3464237..is it posiible to move the mdf file to sql server folder and try..

Answer (score 0):

What's the specific exception message you got?

Please remove "User Instance=False" from your connection string and try it again. Can your code successfuly connect to mdf file with the new connection?

Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I removed "User Instance=False" and It did not help.

I am trying to open two database files, which have a names: database2 and database111. I copied this databases from project and then delete from project.
At now I got next exception:
Unable to attach the database, which automatically was given the name of the file database2. A database with the same name already exists, the specified file can not be opened, or it is on the general resursya UNC.

Comment: I can successfully to open Mdf in project.

Comment: I can successfully to open Mdf in project using your code.
Are you using SQL Server or SQL Server Express, I'm using SQL Server and the connection string does not start with "@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;", you can add the mdf file by using Visual Studio "Connect to database..." and check connection string in property.